# Want to find minimum and maximum from the dataframe

Tags: python

I have a following dataframe which contains minimum and maximums.
Index is index number(frame numbers). B is also index number i.e Frame numbers(Just inserted it to compare values.)

```
index    B  A
    43  43  0.0
    49  49  1.0
    52  52  17.0
    53  53  3.0
    59  59  16.0
    63  63  2.0
    67  67  19.0
    70  70  2.0
    75  75  0.0
    76  76  0.0
    85  85  0.0
    110 110 0.0
    114 114 15.0
    121 121 0.0
    122 122 0.0
    127 127 18.0
    131 131 1.0
    137 137 1.0
    140 140 19.0
    147 147 0.0
    153 153 0.0
```

Now from this dataframe, I want values in such a way that I will have minimum followed by a maximum. If there are mulitple minimum or maximums, I have to keep only one of them. To select one of the minimums, we will substract the index of minima and next maxima and one which gives us value in between 3 to 25 is to be selected and other has to be removed. If there is big gap in frame numbers i.e if subtraction of frame numbers is more than 30 then we keep both minima or maxima.

Expected Output should be somewhat like this:

```
index    B  A
    43  43  0.0
    52  52  17.0
    53  53  3.0
    59  59  16.0
    63  63  2.0
    67  67  19.0
    70  70  2.0
    110 110 0.0
    114 114 15.0
    121 121 0.0
    127 127 18.0
    137 137 1.0
    140 140 19.0
    147 147 0.0
```

Comment: How do you define a minima vs. a maxima? Which ever is below or above the mean value of column `A`?

Comment: in this example you removed only those lines whose values in A which were duplicates. Where is example with a more than 30?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim I was talking here about index(frame numbers) like 85 and 110. There are lot of other such files where i get some other sort of result, so just asked for general solution. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to remove the successive duplicates from the values. In your example outcome it is not clear if you want to keep the last of the first duplicates. You do both. So i decided to go for the last.

First let's rebuild your example DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# rebuild the example data frame
idx = [43, 49, 52, 53, 59, 63, 67, 70, 75, 76, 85, 110, 114, 121, 122, 127, 131, 137, 140, 147, 153]
values = [0.0, 1.0, 17.0, 3.0, 16.0, 2.0, 19.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 1.0,
          1.0, 19.0, 0.0, 0.0]

data = np.array(list(zip(idx, values)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=idx, columns=['B', 'A'])
```

Now let's find the last successive duplicates:

```py
# get the indices of the rows which are successive duplicates
rows_to_drop = []
prev_val = None
prev_idx = None
for index, value in df['A'].iteritems():
    if prev_val is not None and value == prev_val:
        # replace `prev_idx` with `index` if you want to remove the first duplicate
        rows_to_drop.append(prev_idx)
    prev_val = value
    prev_idx = index
df_clean = df.drop(rows_to_drop)
```

For the purpose of demonstrating this produces the expected output:

The original DataFrame:

```
         B     A
43    43.0   0.0
49    49.0   1.0
52    52.0  17.0
53    53.0   3.0
59    59.0  16.0
63    63.0   2.0
67    67.0  19.0
70    70.0   2.0
75    75.0   0.0
76    76.0   0.0
85    85.0   0.0
110  110.0   0.0
114  114.0  15.0
121  121.0   0.0
122  122.0   0.0
127  127.0  18.0
131  131.0   1.0
137  137.0   1.0
140  140.0  19.0
147  147.0   0.0
153  153.0   0.0
```

The cleaned DataFrame:

```
         B     A
43    43.0   0.0
49    49.0   1.0
52    52.0  17.0
53    53.0   3.0
59    59.0  16.0
63    63.0   2.0
67    67.0  19.0
70    70.0   2.0
110  110.0   0.0
114  114.0  15.0
122  122.0   0.0
127  127.0  18.0
137  137.0   1.0
140  140.0  19.0
153  153.0   0.0
```

**Update** If you only want to keep the values where the index distance between duplicates is inbetween 3-25 you may do so by adding an additional condition: `and index - prev_idx in range(2, 26)`:

```py
# get the indices of the rows which are successive duplicates
rows_to_drop = []
prev_val = None
prev_idx = None
for index, value in df['A'].iteritems():
    if prev_val is not None \
            and value == prev_val \
            and index - prev_idx in range(2, 26):
        # replace `prev_idx` with `index` if you want to remove the first duplicate
        rows_to_drop.append(prev_idx)
    prev_val = value
    prev_idx = index
df_clean = df.drop(rows_to_drop)
```

This would change the output to the following, which is not consistent with your example output.

```
         B     A
43    43.0   0.0
49    49.0   1.0
52    52.0  17.0
53    53.0   3.0
59    59.0  16.0
63    63.0   2.0
67    67.0  19.0
70    70.0   2.0
75    75.0   0.0 < note the additional value here
110  110.0   0.0
114  114.0  15.0
121  121.0   0.0 < note the additional value here
122  122.0   0.0 
127  127.0  18.0
137  137.0   1.0
140  140.0  19.0
153  153.0   0.0
```